# android shows a white screen instead of list view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-intent, android-activity

i have set a simple list view, but it only shows a white screen. in main activity in onOptionsItemSelected, i have the following code.

```
   Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AboutTest.class);
   startActivity(l);
```

what is the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity:**

```
public class AboutTest extends Activity {
String[] list = { "hello1", "hello2", "hello3",
        "hello4", "hello5"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about_test);
    ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Comment: check android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. it may be white. try different item layout  or just add divider to the listview and check the result

Comment: What is the API level of the device or emulator you're testing on?

Comment: what this intent do ?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson it is geny motion api23 galaxy s6

Comment: @Mina Fawzy in onOptionsItemSelected (at main activity) when the user clicks "about" from toolbar, this intent starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)`, but that method will only be called for activities that have set [persistableMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#persistableMode) to true in API level 21 or later.

Instead, you should probably be overriding a different onCreate() like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about_test);
    ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. one more thing. now texts are in white. how can i change them to black?

Comment: Yeah, that's a different problem.  You have white text on a white background.  This is a matter changing the theme for your app.  simple_list_item_1 uses `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"` to define how the text looks.  You can instead find the source for simple_list_item_1 and copy it and use your own TextView resource, or you can mess with the styles. That's a whole different issue....